# How to set Jenkinsfile for upload maven artifact to Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I've my .Jenkinsfile like this:

```
properties([[$class: 'GitLabConnectionProperty', gitLabConnection: 'gitlab@srv']])
node {
  env.JAVA_HOME = tool 'JDK 7'
  def mvnHome = tool 'Maven 3.2.2'
  def nodeJS = tool 'IA_NodeJS'
  env.PATH = "${mvnHome}/bin:${nodeJS}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"

  stage ('checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }

  stage ('build') {
    gitlabCommitStatus("build") {
      // your build steps
      sh 'mvn clean install -Denv=dev -P !faster'
    }
  }

  stage ('upload') {
    gitlabCommitStatus("upload") {
      def server = Artifactory.server "artifactory@ibsrv02"
      def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
      buildInfo.env.capture = true
      buildInfo.env.collect()

      def uploadSpec = """{
        "files": [
          {
            "pattern": "**/target/*.jar",
            "target": "libs-snapshot-local"
          }, {
            "pattern": "**/target/*.pom",
            "target": "libs-snapshot-local"
          }, {
            "pattern": "**/target/*.war",
            "target": "libs-snapshot-local"
          }
        ]
      }"""
      // Upload to Artifactory.
      server.upload spec: uploadSpec, buildInfo: buildInfo

      buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, maxDays: 7, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
      // Publish build info.
      server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
  }
}
```

with this method jenkins uploads artifacts without make the "maven's style" layout (packages subfolder and poms).

I want to upload resulting artifact to Artifactory like a normal job uploads it with "Maven3-Artifactory Integration" checked.

Comment: Why not using `mvn deploy`?

Comment: i'm converting jobs to jenkinsfile that are made without `mvn deploy`. i would like to convert it without make changes on poms. @khmarbaise if isn't possible, i'll change poms

Comment: Also, some of us have subsequent stages which must also succeed in order for the merge/pull request to be accepted.  Using mvn deploy causes artifacts to be deployed even for a rejected pull request where the code that built them does not get merged in.  (Not to mention that I personally prefer not to provide the ability for developers to deploy artifacts from unknown build environments/configurations.  Like to isolate to the CI builds.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Artifactory Jenkins plugin version 2.7.2 you can run Maven and Gradle using  [Artifactory pipeline DSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin).

Using the new DSL your build script would look like this:

```
  def server = Artifactory.server "artifactory@ibsrv02"
  def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  buildInfo.env.capture = true
  def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
  rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
  rtMaven.opts = "-Denv=dev"
  rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
  rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-release', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot', server: server

  rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo

  buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, maxDays: 7, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
  // Publish build info.
  server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

You can find more Artifactory pipeline DSL examples in the [jenkins-pipeline-examples](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples).

Comment: thanks, is exactly what i wanted! for bug or feature request can i submit its on github?

Comment: For bug report or feature request it's better to communicate through the  [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin Jira](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/projects/HAP/issues).
Jenkins Artifactory plugin is an open source project, you can always contribute code by sending a pull request to [jenkins-artifactory-plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jenkins-artifactory-plugin) project.

Comment: @TamirHadad Is there any way to decouple the execution of maven goals from the upload of the compiled maven artifacts such that I can just specify some maven coordinates to the plugin and they will be uploaded?

Comment: Nice. But is there also a pure declarative pipeline solution?

Comment: @Ianoxx - Exactly.  I also need to decouple.  Otherwise my build stage ends up deploying maven artifacts when a later stage (running qualys scan, pushing docker images, or publishing API docs) can fail and reject the merge/pull request.  So far I haven't found a way to decouple using Artifactory plugin, though it is decoupled in old maven jobs in Jenkins.  Might have to go custom.

Comment: @Enrice - Yes.  https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile