# suggested workflow for artifactory and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm new to artifactory, have some basic question.
Unfortunately did not find best practices/suggested workflows in the jfrog docs.. As far as I understand there are 2 basic flows for generic build to work with Jenkins:

1. Create tar and with naming convention that holds the build number in it's name (for example my-build-dev-128.tar.gz) and a file ( last-build.txt) that will hold the last build string. So when Jenkins/user needs to download the latest build I download the last-build.txt and get the build number from the string, then download the last artifact.
2. Add   `server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo` to the artifactory upload and then each file has it's own build and that way when you download it has build properties you can work with - however I was not able to pull specific build (have to specify the files that I need and it's always downloading the last build of the file) .

So, what is the best workflow practice for Jenkins/Artifactory marriage ( push , pull, get latest and get older artifacts in automatic way (cli/API/Jenkins plugin - but not GUI)?

Comment: Hi! Is the artifact you want to upload to Artifactory in a maven project? If so, take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39720103/8442153).

Comment: no, it is generic project

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to publish a build info like you mentioned. The build doesn't have to be for a single file, it can include multiple ones.
See these examples for [declarative](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/exclude-patterns-download-example/Jenkinsfile) or [scripted](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/exclude-patterns-download-example/Jenkinsfile) workflows.

When you download, the download command accepts a [file spec](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema).
In the `build` field of the file spec you can specify a build name without a build number which will download the artifacts of the latest build.
When you specify a build, the `aql` and `pattern` fields are optional. You can still use them if you'd like to filter some of the build artifacts.

An additional file to hold the build details is redundant, this is what the build info is for.

Comment: I my case I want to store the artifacts in different folders, according to the branch build ( for example in case of DEV branch build I want to save the artifacts in DEV folder of the artifactory, and STAGE for staging branch). When I  try to download the latest artifact from DEV folder via file spec it fails ( seems LATEST is global per repository - so if the last global push is in STAGE and this file spec returns nothing).
`"pattern": "repo/DEV","build": "OG/LATEST"`
Is there easier/more elegant way to get latest build from specific folder or I have get the  that last build via API/AQL ?